# Saving file name as a variable

Tags: c#

Is there a way to save a file equal to a variable in Visual C#?

I'm using a program to automate MS Word documents and would like them saved with a generic title + the days date.

The following lines of code do not work.

```
DateTime Tomorrow = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
string OKD; 
OKD = Tomorrow.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
document.SaveAs(FileName: @"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Generic name "+ OKD +".doc");
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't very helpful for us. What doesn't work .. ?

Comment: sorry. By it doesn't work i mean it won't save and the program won't run

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't work because you have `/` in your file name. Save as a date format that can be used as a filename:

```
OKD = Tomorrow.ToString("MMddyyyy");
document.SaveAs(FileName: @"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\GenericName" + OKD +".doc");
```

Comment: Or even `yyyyMMdd` so it will be shown in a sensible order in file listings.

Comment: Or even `yyyy.MM.dd` to add some clear visual separation to the document list (and ordering as above).

Comment: Perfect! thanks. I'm still a programming noob, should have remembered that you can't save documents with the "/" key in the file name.